# Bootstrap navbar not adjusting on mobile browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make the navbar responsive to work on any mobile browser and adjust according to the browser window, but for some reason when I load the website on a mobile browser (Chrome) it only shows/collapses the options for a moment and then the navbar stays fixed stretching to make a one page bootstrap website into a two page (book type) website where all of the website content is on the left and the right side is blank

Here is the code of the navbar

HTML Code

```
   <head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>NDT Solution - Home</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">

<!-- Plugin CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css" type="text/css">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/creative.css" type="text/css">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="js/creative.js"></script>

</head>
      <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">NDT Solution</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#team">Our Team</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

CSS

```
  Default bootstrap css files
```

Answer (score -1):

.container has one fixed width for each screen size in bootstrap (xs,sm,md,lg); .container-fluid expands to fill the available width. You're fine to use fluid.

Do you have the following tag in your head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Which tag are you referring to? container-fluid?

Comment: Sorry, meant to add    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: Yes, I have this tag in the head

Comment: Any chance you could post what is between your head tags? I've ran the code you have supplied and it looks fine.